# Help verifying a numerical inequality

Tags: inequality

Suppose that $\gamma_1, \dots, \gamma_n$ are positive, increasing, real numbers.
Is it true that if $\alpha_i$ are nonnegative and sum to $A$, then
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i^2 \alpha_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i \alpha_i}
- \sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i \alpha_i \geq (1-A) \gamma_1?
$$

This is easy to check for $n = 1$:
$$
\gamma_1 - \gamma_1 \alpha_1 = (1 - A) \gamma_1. 
$$
I am having trouble checking for $n \geq 2$. One thing I noticed is that by rescaling, we may assume $\gamma_1 = 1$, without loss.

Answer (score 1):

This inequality is true for $A \in (0, 1]$ but false for $A > 1$. For example, take $n = 2, \gamma_1 = 1, \gamma_2 = 2, \alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = 1$.

To see the inequality for $A \in (0, 1]$, just note that if $G = \mathbf{diag}(\gamma_1, \dots, \gamma_n)$, then
$$
\|G\alpha\| \geq \frac{\alpha^T G \alpha}{\|\alpha\|}. 
$$
Therefore,
$$
\|G\alpha\|^2 - (\alpha^T G \alpha)^2 \geq (1 - \|\alpha\|^2) \lambda_{\rm min}(G) = (1 - \|\alpha\|^2) \gamma_1 (\alpha^T G \alpha).
$$
Replacing $\alpha \mapsto \sqrt{\alpha}$, using the bound on $\alpha$, and rearranging gives the result.